# Spatialite 'SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics()' returns "0"

Tags: spatialite

I have got several sqlite-databases (some geneated from within qgis 2.14.0/2.16.2). When running `SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics()` to the databases some results are "0" and some are "1". 
A `PRAGMA integrity_check;` to the databases with "0"-result haves the result "OK". 
Running the `SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics('myTableNames')` against all tables within the "0"-result-db have the result "1".

So why is there a "0"-result at several databases when running `SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics()` against the whole db - althrough running the command against every single table returns "1". What can I do to fix the problems and finally get a "1"-result ?

Comment: First thing to do is to point us a test database that can be used for re-producing the "0" case. It is "OK" to get back "0" because that's a valid return of the function, the issue is what prevents layer statistics from updating.

Comment: @ user30184: You can download a reduced sample-database at: [link] https://storage.driveonweb.de/dowdoc/1b057b61db0b2cf2f4432712dff1ebd7838c0ec15614a16c.zip

I’ve reduced the number of tables in the database  from the original db. 
I’ve tried to ‘UpdateLayerStatistics ‘ to every single table within the db but it seems that `select UpdateLayerStatistics(‘InvalidTableName or ValidTableName’)`or `select UpdateLayerStatistics(“InvalidTableName or ValidTableName”)` returns “1” althrough the invalid tablenames do not exist and a “0” is expected in this case.

Comment: I do not know well this part of the metadata of SpatiaLite, but I wonder why there are more rows in the geometry_columns_statistics than in geometry_columns even there seems to be a constraint `CONSTRAINT fk_gc_statistics FOREIGN KEY (f_table_name, f_geometry_column) REFERENCES geometry_columns (f_table_name, f_geometry_column) ON DELETE CASCADE)`. It feels like the metadata is somehow corrupted.